# How can I grep string with quotes and colopn

Tags: linux

How can I grep a string with quotes and colon :
Eg I  want to grep something like this ? `"name": "Somename"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just escape quotes `grep '\"Somename\"'`

[image]

Comment: what about   ":" ? I mean ' \"name\": \"Somename\"'  will it work without escaping colon ?

Comment: @danishsodhi check uploaded image. It should tell You all :)